# Why are links in my Rails app doing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a link in my Rails app, it's supposed to be a toggle for jQuery, and looks like this:

```
<span id="listings-toggle"><a>sold listings</a></span>
```

The reason I haven't added an `href="#"` tag is because whenever I do that, upon clicking the link the toggle action will happen but then revert itself back to the default state. One div is shown by default, you click the toggle to switch to the other, but then within a second or two it  switches back to the default state on its own. When I remove href, however, this doesn't happen and the toggle works fine.

I checked the requests that happen when I have href in the anchor tag and for some reason the GET route for the current page is always called upon clicking it. Why? Obviously removing the href line means that the mouse cursor doesn't indicate it to be clickable when hovered over. What might be going on? All I'm doing in my href tag is "#", so it shouldn't be calling the page again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default action on your `click` event using `e.preventDefault()` and that will stop the revert. Alternatively, you can add `cursor: pointer` to your style rules and not have to have a `href` attribute